# How can I make a Twitter Bootstrap styled form have multiple inputs in a row?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

From official docs:

> Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of
>   form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the
>   form (which doesn't have to be a ). Doing so changes
>   .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row.

So I tried:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-2 form-control" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-6 form-control" placeholder="Unidad">
    </div>  
</form>
```

But it seems the `form-control` class will make them return to an own single row each.

This is what I got:

[image]
How can I achieve both input to be placed in same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `form-inline` to the form class. Note that, if you make the form too small, it will still 'spill over'. In this case, and if you don't want all `form-group`s to be inline, use separate divs for the spacing.

Form inline example:

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<form class="form-horizontal form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 form-control" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 form-control" placeholder="Unidad">
    </div>  
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Separate Div example:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxkvnz6f/3/)

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" class=" form-control" placeholder="Cantidad" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" class=" form-control" placeholder="Unidad" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</form>
</div></div>
```

Comment: That makes the rest of my `form-groups` to get *inline* too, what I don't want

Comment: Can you offer an example using it?

Comment: OK nvm after tinkering I think the easiest thing is to use separate divs for the spacing, I'll update my answer

Comment: Yeah, I just tried with separate divs and got results... now just do you have any idea how to drop off the padding (is it even a padding?) that each div will get the way they won't match " parent " width?

Comment: yeah there is a bit of a margin, you can either do a manual override in the element's `style` attribute or override the `col-md-*` margin itself

Comment: Tried with padding and got results ... `padding-left: 0px !important`

Comment: I guess that more than giving an extra fiddle, you should replace it over the first snippet :)

Comment: And I'm still asking why you want to add `pull-left` class to each input?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-2  pull-left" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input type="text" class="col-md-6  pull-left" placeholder="Unidad">
    </div>  
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/uey4spe4/)

Comment: Adding `form-control` class will automatically break it